# Naming non-zero vectors in $A$ given $Ax$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am struggling with solving the following:

> Suppose that $A$ is a matrix and that $$ Ax = Ay = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$ where $x\neq y$.
>
> 1. Name a non-zero vector in Nul($A$). Briefly justify your answer.
> 2. Name a non-zero vector in Col($A$). Briefly justify your answer.
> 3. Name an eigenvalue for $A$ and a corresponding eigenvector. Briefly justify your answer.

---

I apologize in advance for my lack of understanding, however I am fully stumped from the get-go for this problem, how would I solve to find the non-zero vectors from here?

Comment: Think about matrices as linear maps. So $A(x-y)=Ax-Ay=(1,0,1)^T-(1,0,1)^T=0$. Please try something yourself and add it to the post (avoid "no clue" questions, see the guidelines).

Comment: Where does this come from?

Comment: [Here are some guidelines on how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960).

Answer (score 1):

Think of $A$ as the matrix representation of an operator in a certain basis.
The column vectors of this operator correspond to the vectors you get when acting on the basis vectors.
Suppose your basis is
$$E=\{(1,0,0)^T,(0,1,0)^T,(0,0,1)^T\}$$
And suppose you want to map
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\0\\0
\end{pmatrix}\xrightarrow{A}
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\2\\3
\end{pmatrix}\\[0.1cm]
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\1\\0
\end{pmatrix}\xrightarrow{A}
\begin{pmatrix}
4\\5\\6
\end{pmatrix}\\[0.1cm]
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\0\\1
\end{pmatrix}\xrightarrow{A}
\begin{pmatrix}
7\\8\\9
\end{pmatrix}\\[0.1cm]
\end{align}
The matrix $A$, in the basis $E$ would be represented as:
\begin{gather}
A=
\begin{pmatrix}
1&4&7\\
2&5&8\\
3&6&9
\end{pmatrix}
\end{gather}
Can you work out the answer from here?

Answer (score 1):

1. The Null space of A is the space of all vectors in $ \mathrm{R}^3 $ that are mapped to the zero vector (also in $ \mathrm{R}^3 $)
   $$ \mathcal{N} (A) = \{x \in \mathrm{R}^3 | Ax = 0 \in \mathrm{R}^3\} $$

Note that the zero vector trivially belongs to the null space of every matrix.
Here, we can see
$$ A(x-y) = Ax - Ay = 0 \implies (x-y) \in \mathcal{N}(A) $$

Since $x \neq y $, $(x-y) \neq 0 $ and thus we have our answer.

2. The column space of a matrix is the space of image vectors, i.e. the vectors to which the vectors in the domain are mapped.
   Here,
   $$ \mathcal{C}(A) = \{ Ax : x \in \mathrm{R}^3 \} $$

Clearly, one such vector is $ (1, 0, 1)^T $. This solves the second part.

3. Eigenvectors of a linear transformation are non-zero vectors that are mapped to a scaled version of themselves. The corresponding scaling factors are known as eigenvalues.
   In short, an eigenvector $v \in \mathrm{R}^3$ of $A$, with eignevalue $\lambda$ would be such that
   $$ Av = \lambda v \in \mathrm{R}^3 $$
   In this case, we can use the solution of the first part of the question to deduce that an eigenvector of $A$ if $(x-y)$, with correspinding eigenvalue $0$.

Hope this helps.